# Vuetify problems with the width of a v-col

Tags: vuetify.js

I would like to set the v-col width with the h1, in the code below, to 100% of the page, how can i do it?

```
<v-main class="pt-0 black" max-width="auto">
    <v-row>
        <v-col cols="auto">
            <v-img src="@/assets/images/riot-logo.png"></v-img>
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="auto">
          <v-container class="riot-text">
            <h1 class="text-center">Riot Games</h1>
          </v-container>
        </v-col>
    </v-row>
</v-main>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The columns are adjacent to one another, so you can't make one 100% without setting the other to zero.  In order to set the column to width 100%, you will need to place each column in it's own row. [I also removed](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-playground-forked-mzj8x?file=/src/layout.vue) the `cols="auto"` attribute.

```
<v-main class="pt-0" max-width="auto">
            <v-row>
                <v-col cols="auto">
                    <v-img src="@/assets/images/riot-logo.png"></v-img>
                </v-col>
            </v-row>
            <v-row>
                <v-col>
                    <v-container class="riot-text fluid">
                        <h1 class="text-center">Riot Games</h1>
                    </v-container>
                </v-col>
            </v-row>
        </v-main>
```

Comment: Got it, thanks, but I think I did not well-explain my question, and sorry for that, my english is not that good (also its my first post here). I want to make the 2 cols stay side by side, and the col with the h1 to occupy all the remaining space on the side of the image, so I can have the text-center class working on it. For example: the image occupy 60% of the row and the container 40% of it.

Comment: Just remove the `cols="auto"` from the column with the h1. It will take up the remaining space not occupied by the first column.

Comment: I managed to do it by changing the cols of img as cols="8" and the col of h1 as cols="4" and it worked. Thanks for the help!